# Fill rectangle with Image from resource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles

I have rectangle which I want to fill with different pictures based on property. I created a binding to bool variable and styles. But code does not work.

Error: Cannot convert ystem.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage to System.Windows.Media.Brush

```
<Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Canvas.Left="{Binding x}"  Canvas.Top="{Binding y}">
 <Rectangle.Style>
  <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
   <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding teamgreen}" Value="True">
     <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource tankGreen}" />
    </DataTrigger>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding teamgreen}" Value="False">
     <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource tankBlue}"/>
    </DataTrigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
 </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

tankGreen and tankBlue look like this

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="tankBlue" UriSource="..\Images\tankBlue.png" />
<BitmapImage x:Key="tankGreen" UriSource="..\Images\tankGreen.png" />
```

they work fine when I use

```
<Rectangle.Fill>                               
 <ImageBrush ImageSource="{DynamicResource tankBlue}" />
</Rectangle.Fill>
```

I guess I just dont know how to incorporate ImageBrush into style for datatrigger setter

Comment: You could simply use an Image control instead of a Rectangle, and set its Source property to the one or the other BitmapImage by DataTriggers.

Comment: Yes I know but I will need some other properties from Rectangle later in the project. So I need to do this with rectangles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `Setter.Value` just like you set `Rectangle.Fill`:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding teamgreen}" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Fill">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{DynamicResource tankGreen}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>    
</DataTrigger>
```